# How to deal with a generic object in C++

Tags: c++, json, generics, c++11

What is the proper way to deal with a generic value in C++11 or is it OK to use (void *)?

Basically, I am parsing json, and the node value can either be String, Integer, Double, Date, etc.

In C, just using void * is OK (not safe, but ok), and in C# we use Object.   But what is the proper way in C++11 to do this?   Do I have to build a wrapper class, or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a base class for the various types, or use a "discriminated union" class such as [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/variant.html) which holds a known set of types and remembers which one it is holding.

Comment: I forgot to stipulate...not using Boost.   But yes, equivalent to that.

Comment: Well, if you don't want to use Boost you can just do what it does.  "Discriminated union" is the key term to search for. Plenty of implementations.

Comment: That is the path I was actually looking at, but wasn't sure if unions were considered acceptable.

Comment: So, is the only 2 techniques are suitable for this: type erasure + RTTI and discriminated union?

Comment: @VictorPolevoy: other solutions are possible.  For example, on amd64 machines, one can use the top several bits of a pointer to store other information, so you could for example store 64-bit objects which could be ref-counted pointers to char arrays, 32-bit integers, 32-bit floats, epoch timestamps, and more.  But that's non-portable and way more hardcore than most applications warrant.